# libreoffice calc - average of sums

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Let's say I have some data on columns B through E that I want to average as follows:

- for each row: sum the four columns
- then take the average such sum

Do I *have* to get another column for the sum and then take the average of that column or is there a more direct approach? Because pulling `=SUM(...)` down `500'000` rows **does** take a while.

Answer (score 1):

This formula works in Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B500000+C1:C500000+D1:D500000+E1:E500000)/COUNT(B1:B500000)
```

[image]

Comment: Hm... And there isn't a way that would allow me to use the average function? Because the next thing I need are percentiles of these sums.